# mysql update statement using the from clause on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

The following is the MS Sql server Update statement

```
    Update 
        HC_TranDetails
SET
        InsPayments = (SELECT IsNull(SUM(ISNULL(CreditAmount,0)),0) From HC_TranDetails TDS
                        Where TDS.TransactionType = 2 
                        AND TDS.ClaimNo = TD.ClaimNo 
                        AND TDS.LineItemNo = TD.LineItemNo 
                        AND IsNull(TDS.InsPlanRowID,'') <> ''
                        AND TDS.ReverseEntry <> 1 ),

        Adjustments = (SELECT IsNull(SUM(ISNULL(CreditAmount,0)),0) From HC_TranDetails TDS
                        Where TDS.TransactionType = 8
                        AND TDS.ClaimNo = TD.ClaimNo 
                        AND TDS.LineItemNo = TD.LineItemNo 
                        AND IsNull(TDS.InsPlanRowID,'') <> ''
                        AND TDS.ReverseEntry <> 1 ),


FROM
        HC_TranDetails TD
```

Now i am trying the same kind of statement in mysql as follows

```
    UPDATE claimdetails SET balanceAmount =  (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(IFNULL(debitamount,0)) -  SUM(IFNULL(creditamount,0)),0) 
                      FROM claimdetail CD WHERE CD.claimID = CDS.claimID)

FROM ClaimDetail CDS
```

But it is showing as syntax Error near 'From ClaimDetail CDS' at line 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is squeamish about updates on the same table.  The easy fix is to include an extra level of subquery.  The proper fix, though, is to use a join

```
UPDATE claimdetails join
       (select claimid, IFNULL(SUM(IFNULL(debitamount,0)) -  SUM(IFNULL(creditamount,0)),0) as val
        from ClaimDetails
        group by claimid
       ) agg
       on claimdetails.claimid = agg.claimid
    SET balanceAmount = agg.val;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the table you want to update with a subquery that calculates the balance for each `claimid` on the other table.

By using `LEFT JOIN`, it will update all records on table `claimdetails`. A value of `0` will be updated to any non existent `claimid` on the subquery.

```
UPDATE  claimdetails a
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  claimID, 
                    SUM(IFNULL(debitamount, 0)) - SUM(IFNULL(creditamount,0)) bal
            FROM    claimdetail
            GROUP   BY claimID
        ) b ON a.claimID = b.claimID
SET     a.balanceAmount = IFNULL(b.bal, 0)
```